# Upgrade design of graphicdesign.SE to look more like meta.photo.SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I really like the look and feel of http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com

It is so much more aesthetically appealing than that of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

(which is basically just using the cookie-cutter- stackexchange design)

I propose that we upgrade graphicdesign.SE to have a better design/ layout.

Answer (score 7):

I think that we can do much better, and a competition would be nice to do as design proposal

Comment: +1 @Littlemad : I like the idea of having a design competition

Comment: I would *hope* that the *Graphic Design* se site could do better...  :-)

Answer (score 6):

I doubt I'll ever do a dark theme on a main site. The [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/design-for-physics-se) site had a dark design and it didn't go too well. I had to pull it after its launch. Meta.Photo was an exception because it was a meta site.

As for the design for this site, it's possible that we may launch its final theme before the site officially graduates. I think it'd help the site's growth since our main users are designers. The "Sketchy" beta theme was purposely designed to make the site look incomplete, but I can understand it may turn off potential new designer users.

Answer (score 5):

ooh, please no white text on dark background. hard on the eyes.

Comment: actually it is easier to read because of the high contrast ;)

Comment: +1 @Littlemad : My personal preference is for light on dark too. @Lauren Even if we stick with dark on light, I'm sure we can come up with a much better design than the present one!

Comment: high contrast aside, it should be off black and off white, the two extremes are far too much. The words can appear to "shake"

Comment: @Daniel - like red text on blue? Haha...

Comment: @Shango You're sick!!!  ;)